# In mapreduce how reducer finds which partition of map output to pull

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In map-reduce, after the map process generates partitioned output. After that reducer pulls a specific partition data from different mappers. Here how a reducer knows which partition of the data it has to pull from the mapper's output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is determined by the partitioning mechanism. The default partitioning mechanism is ***Hash Partitioning***.But you can define a custom partitioner for this.

Example for *custom partitioner* :-

```
public class Custom_Partitioner extends Partitioner<Text, IntWritable> {
    @Override
    public int getPartition(Text key, IntWritable value, int numPartitions) {
        String myKey = key.toString().toLowerCase();
        if (myKey.startsWith("a")) {
            return 0;
        } else if (myKey.startsWith("e")) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

And in the driver code :-

```
job.setPartitionerClass(Custom_Partitioner.class);
job.setNumReduceTasks(3);
```

So here, we have set the number of reducer task as 3 and coded the partitioner according to that which is self expalanatory. 
Thank you.!

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). My understanding was, partition happens on the map side, reducer pulls the data based on the partition it is assigned to. So how the reducer knows which partition it is assigned to